# Subgroup of order n of group of order 2n

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

There is a subgroup of order $n$ in a group of order $2n$. Prove, that all squares of elements lie in this subgroup.

I thought about some solution, with the usage of Lagrange theorem and normality of this subgroup, but I didn't come up with anything good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The subgroup of order  $n $ is normal.  Thus $G/N $ is a group of order $2$.  There are two equivalence classes, $N $ and $xN $, for some $x\in G $.  If $g\in N $, then $g^2\in N $, since  $N $ is a subgroup.   If $g\notin N $, then  $g=xn $ for some  $n\in N$.  But then $g^2=x^2n'\in N $, since $xN $ has order two.

Comment: Why the $g^2 = xnxn = x^2n$?

Comment: @TimCreig The elements of the quotient group $G/N$ are $N$ and $Ng$ (for $g \notin N$), and since the quotient group is a group, by Lagrange's Theorem, the element $Ng$ must have order $2$, which means $NgNg=Ng^2=N$, which means $g^2=n$.  It's not necessarily the case that $g$ commutes with any particular element of $N$.

Comment: Thanks, now it's clear!

Comment: Well I don't find it clear! It's not true that $(xn)^2 = xn$. It should be $(xn)^2 = x^2n'$ for some $n' \in N$.

Comment: Exactly @DerekHolt  I was thinking the same thing.  Will edit.